# iOS app with remote server - I don't need data to persist on app, should I still use CoreData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Design question:

My app talks to a server. Json data being sent/received.

Data on server is always changing, and I want users to see most current data, not stored/cached data. So I require a user to be logged in order to use the app, and care not to persist data in the app.

Should I still use CoreData and map it to Json's.?

Or can I just create custom model classes and map Json's to it's properties, and have nsarray properties, which point to its child objects, etc. ?

Which is better?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to query the data?

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want to persist data, I personally think core data would be overkill for this application

Answer (score 1):

Core Data is really for local persistance. If the data was not changing so often and you didnt want them to have to get an updated data everytime the user visited the page, then you would load the JSON and store it locally using CoreData.

Answer (score 0):

Use plain old objective-c objects for now.  It's not hard to switch to Core Data in future, but once you've done so it gets a lot harder to change your schema.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what your needs are.

If you need the app to work offline, you need to store your information somehow in the client.

In order to save on network usage, you could store locally, then query the server to see if it had an updated answer -- you could do this by sending a time stamp to the server and return a 304 Not Modified if the entity hasn't changed.

Generally, it depends on how much time you have to put into the app and what your specific requirements are, but as a general rule I would optimise for as low bandwidth usage as possible, as that not only reduces potential data costs, but also means the answers will be more quickly available to your users (when online and they have not changed) and also available offline.

If you do not wish to store data locally at all,